# Main method error after renaming enclosing class

Tags: c#, rename, program-entry-point

I'm working off the first tutorial on learncs.org and have a question.

Here's the code from the example:

```
using System;

public class Hello
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Goodbye, World!");
    }
}
```

This returns Goodbye, World in the console like shown.
But once I change public class `Hello` to `Hello2` it doesn't work anymore.  The tutorial doesn't show how it's being executed so I don't know how its being done.

Anyone know how I could execute it if I name it Hello2?  I tried this and it didn't quite work:

```
using Hello2.Main();
```

Here's the actual example: [Hello, World!](http://www.learncs.org/en/Hello%2C_World!)

Comment: Typically the class is named `Program`, but if I change it to `Program2` it still works for me.

Comment: Your link is dead :)

Comment: Each project has a "startup object" property.  Make sure that's changed to `Hello2` as well.

Comment: You're running this on the website.  If you were running it from Visual Studio, changing the class name wouldn't affect anything.

Comment: When trying to learn a language you should be not dealing with the tutorial, but the languange instead. Change tutorial, that doesn't looks good. Pick CodeAcademy.

Comment: @celerno CodeAcademy doesn't have a c# tutorial?

Comment: Oh, you're right. Sorry. But, seriously, pick another one. It will be better if is one that makes you work directly with Visual Studio.

Comment: Try this free ebook from programmerheaven. it's a little old ,it covers C# 2 but it is very simple : http://ebooks.programmersheaven.com/csharp_ebook.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The runtime is calling the `Main` function. It normally just finds the first function called `Main` in your program and executes it.

**However** if you explicitly set the startup object in the Application tab of project settings, it will fail if that class does not have a function called `Main` (or if that class doesn't exist).

Try setting it to "(Not Set)" or your newly named class and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

You should set the Startup object for your application. Right click on the Project, go to project properties -> Application, There change the Startup object to `Hello2`.

[image]

Remember, It should work as long as you have a single entry point in your application, i.e. `public static Main` method and you have Startup object specified as `(Not Set)`.

But if you have multiple class with `Main` method, then you have to explicitly specify the Startup object, *(either through GUI or with compile options)* or you will end up with an error:

> Application.exe has more than one entry point defined:
>   'Application.Hello2.Main()'.  Compile with /main to specify the type
>   that contains the entry point.

Comment: Why does it have to be a startup class?  Why can't it just be used whenever I want to use it?

Comment: @ZeeTee the problem is that you are *not* using it whenever you want to. *Something* needs to start. That could then call whatever you want. You are not doing that, but changing where the `main` is.

Comment: @ZeeTee, The runtime has to follow specs, and the specs says to find entry point in the application and then execute it. As I said in my answer, if you only have single `Main` method, then your change in Class name should work as long as you have specified Startup object to Not Set.